# MS Graph Onenote API endpoint not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

1. There are three example URLs on this page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote-get-content
   Only the first one works.

   - graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notes/pages got 400 BadRequest - Resource not found for the segment 'notes'.
   - graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages?select=title,self got 404 Not Found with error code 20102 and The specified resource ID does not exist.
2. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/2c568d5b67f2d066a2a85fb4292e8d7efe317b97/docs/overview.md the example line of 
   *await graphClient.Me.Onenote.Sections.Request().GetAsync()* is also not working. Get 20102 too.
3. For Full Rest URL

   - graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks works.
   - graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{notebook_id} works.
   - graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{notebook_id}/sections works.
   - But graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{notebook_id}/sections/{section_id} does not work.
     section_id is from the section list got from graph api. It will return with 404 Not Found with error below.

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "UnknownError",
>           "message": "{\r\n  \"Message\": \"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'https://www.onenote.com/api/V1.0/users({user_id})/notes/notebooks({notebook_id})/sections({section_id})'.\"\r\n}",
>           "innerError": {
>               "request-id": xxxxxx,
>               "date": xxxxxx
>           }
>       } }

Also not working with graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{notebook_id}/sections/{section_id}/pages

4. How can I read one page from my Onenote? I got NO DOCS or EXAMPLES can help me now.
5. Where is DOC for Graph SDK?

Answer (score 2):

1.I think you may need to call the API interface like：
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/onenote/sections/{section-id}/pages`  or
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{section-id}/pages`
to read all pages from your Onenote.
2.You can call the Microsoft Graph API to get one page's content, and the request url like this:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{pageid}/content`
3.You can get the content of the Graph API: [https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview)
4.Here are the Docs for Graph: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks
5. I think you may need [the graph explore](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to try some APIs. It has intellisense.

If you have further questions, please leave the comments below.